# Invalidate Guava cache by the part of the key

Tags: java, caching, guava

I am using Guava LoadingCache for caching auth requests for the external storage. The key is the object Auth:

```
public class Auth {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    public boolean equals(Object o);
}
```

and the response is HttpStatus, OK or FORBIDDEN.

When the password for `username` in external storage is changed, I need to remove cache record for `username`, but the problem is that the passwords storing only as a hash, not the original value, so I can't just construct new Auth object for invalidation, like:

```
cache.invalidate(new Auth(<username>, <password>));
```

How can I invalidate cache record, using only `username` value?

Comment: Why not use `Auth` as the key?

Comment: Cause I don't know the original password, only the stored MD5 hash. And in the cache I have Auth with the original password, so they not equal.

Comment: I feel silly, what I meant to ask is, "Why not use `username` as the key"?

Comment: And how it must work?  For example, I got two records in cache: Auth(user1, password1) = OK and Auth(user1, password2) = FORBIDDEN. So password1 is correct, and password2 is incorrect. If I'll receive more one request with Auth(user1, password2) , I just return FORBIDDEN without quering the external storage. If I will use only username as a key, I will need to query the storage every time I receive request.

Answer (score 4):

> For example, I got two records in cache: Auth(user1, password1) = OK and Auth(user1, password2) = FORBIDDEN. So password1 is correct, and password2 is incorrect. If I'll receive more one request with Auth(user1, password2) , I just return FORBIDDEN without querying the external storage.

The problem with this is that you'll hardly ever see `Auth(user1,  password2)` (i.e., an invalid pair) again. A legitimate user can make a mistake and they might repeat exactly the same mistake, but that's rare. An attacker won't waste time with repeating a failed combination. So such an entry is just wasted memory.

Storing `user` as the key and `password` or `hashedPassword` as the value should work well and in case of a hit it will save you the external storage access: all you need is a comparison and hashing.

*While I don't think that your problem makes sense*, I try to propose a solution: Invalidating by a part of a key is impossible, but you can instead keep a set of all users having changed their password recently (e.g., in the last 24 hours). If you set `expireAfterWrite` to a smaller value, then you can be sure that an invalid `Auth` can be detected by consulting the set.

**Note that protecting passwords by MD5 only is very week.** There are much better algorithms like `bcrypt` or `bcrypt`, designed for slowing down password cracking.

Answer (score 1):

How about implementing a RemovalListener that executes on an eviction and removes the key e.g. username from a separate data structure that is based on key value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

What about

- walk through the cache keys
- look for changed user
- invalidate the key

The second option is using `user` as the cache key and `the password hash` as the value instead of the caching of the service response

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion caching password instead hash is not good practice.
The key could be only username or username and hash.